# Display a range on a number line with a value

Tags: numbers, timeline, range

Is there a standard or good way to display a range of values (lower bound and upper bound) along with a particular value. The particular value might be too low (below the lower bound), too high (above the upper bound, or normal (between the bounds)? As in results from a blood test. For example, here's a very crude drawing of those 3 scenarios:
[image]

Maybe a timeline type of interface?

Comment: There are quite a few different range slider type of component design at CodePen that you might like to take a look (https://codepen.io/tag/rangeslider?cursor=ZD0xJm89MCZwPTE=).

Comment: @MichaelLai I’m really trying to figure out how to very clearly layout the information, that there’s a range with lower and upper bounds and a value that may or may not be within the range. A range slider is too different I think to take design cues from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quite easily modify a [bullet graph/chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_graph) for this purpose. I think the timeline component that you are referring to is still just a variation of a range slider. The only difference is that you are displaying a value that shouldn't be adjusted by the user (since it is showing a value derived from some other data source), so that control/interaction will just be disabled).

[image]

Essentially a bullet chart is a more fancy range slider component that has some additional elements:

- range values that can be defined and styled as the background and stacked
- current value that is overlaid on the defined/customized range values
- additional marker to indicate additional values (e.g. previous or estimated value)